# Error while trying to use Azure business to consumer

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to set up Azure B2C for my web site and can never get to the login screen. When I click login on my app I get the following exception:

> InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/XXXX.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signupandsignin/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'. HttpResponseMessage: 'StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found'

My config is:

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/",
    "ClientId": "f4a.................................",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Domain": "XXXX.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_signupandsignin",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_passwordreset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_profileedit"
  }
```

and in my ConfigureServices method in startup.cs I have:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
```

As far as I can see everything is set up correctly (e.g. I've checked that the client Id is the correct Application Id) but I always get this error.

Does anyone have any idea as to what is going wrong?

Comment: Which doc did you refer to?

Comment: Whatever I could find on the Microsoft site, plus other blog posts about it. Trouble is there seems to be a difference in how this has worked over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success. Looks like MS have changed the domain they use for B2C and so the instance is wrong. It should be "https://xxxx.b2clogin.com/tfp/" where the domain is xxxx.onmicrosoft.com

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://xxxx.b2clogin.com/tfp/",
    "ClientId": "f4a.................................",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Domain": "XXXX.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_signupandsignin",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_passwordreset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_profileedit"
  }
```

It was this video that really helped (though I'm sure before too long it will be out of date) -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M23P7tj_bXA

And for the sake of completeness the reason why this is a fix is that MS is migrating to the b2clogin domain - [Azure Active Directory B2C is deprecating login.microsoftonline.com](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/b2c-deprecate-msol/)

Answer (score 0):

Try appending the policy e.g

?p=B2C_1_signupandsignin

to the URL.

Comment: Which URL? It cant go on the Instance as that is used to construct the full URL